# Outbound Change Set

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, error-messages, change-set

I created a test class to test a trigger and I am getting the following error when trying to deploy the change set.  I don't know if the error is with the Test or the change set, error below:

> System.AssertException: Assertion Failed
>   Stack Trace: Class.Test_AutoApprove.t1: line 11, column 1

Test is as follows:

```
@isTest
private class Test_AutoApprove {
static testmethod void t1(){
        Site_Call_Performance__c t = new Site_Call_Performance__c(Status__c=       'Submitted');

test.startTest();
insert t;
update t;
test.stopTest();

System.assert(t.Status__c == 'Approved');
}
}
```

Trigger!

```
trigger AutoApprovebasedoffCheckbox on Site_Call_Performance__c (after update) 
{
List<Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest> reqList = new List<Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest>();
Set<ID> scpIDs = new Set<ID>();
for (Site_Call_Performance__c a : Trigger.new)
{
    if (a.Approval_Checkbox__c)
    {
        scpIDs.add(a.Id);
    }
}

Set<Id> pIds = (new Map<Id, ProcessInstance>([SELECT Id,Status,TargetObjectId FROM ProcessInstance where Status='Pending' and TargetObjectId in :scpIds ])).keySet();
Set<Id> pInstanceWorkitems = (new Map<Id, ProcessInstanceWorkitem>([SELECT Id,ProcessInstanceId FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem WHERE ProcessInstanceId in :pIds])).keySet();

List<Approval.ProcessWorkItemRequest> approve = New List<Approval.ProcessWorkItemRequest>(); 

for (Id pInstanceWorkitemsId : pInstanceWorkitems)
{
    Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest req = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();
    req.setComments('Auto Approved by System');
    req.setAction('Approve'); 
    req.setWorkitemId(pInstanceWorkitemsId);

    approve.add(req);
}

List<Approval.ProcessResult> result = Approval.process(approve);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're testing a trigger, you need to remember to query the database for any changes to the record. This simple change should work (assuming your trigger works):

```
test.stopTest();
t = [select status__c from Site_Call_Performance__c where id = :t.Id];
System.assertEquals('Approved', t.Status__c);
```

*Note: I recommend assertEquals because it prints a friendly message like "Assertion Failed. Expected: Approved, Actual: Not Approved".*

Comment: ok, maybe I am doing this wrong.  I added another field value to the record and it is still not working!  I also used added your suggestions, i think has to be my test because the code works as intended in sandbox.

Comment: @JeffGreen Did you *also* check to make sure you included the trigger and any supporting classes?

Comment: i did,   i am very new at this!  This is the trigger that works in sandbox, is this not the right test for it?  I am getting 60% code coverage.

Comment: @JeffGreen Okay, did you include the correct approval processes, maybe?

Comment: I was planning on using the approval processes in production, do i need to include approval processes?

Comment: @JeffGreen You either need to build it beforehand or include it in the change set.

Answer (score 0):

This is error when test class runs and according to assert condition it will always fail.

There could be some other process exist which could update the status as `Approved`.

So, better to fetch the record from database and compare the results.